# routerLink to load a page of a nested parent->child->child

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use routerLink to load a page of a parent->child->child router outlet with two named outlets.

```
 http://localhost:4200/#/output/(output:details/(data:distributions))
```

1) If I paste the URL into the browser it works

2) If I use the below it works:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('output/(output:details/(data:distributions))');
```

If I try to use router link in an angular2 tab component IT DOES NOT WORK

```
[routerLink]="['/output', {outlets: {'output': ['details'],'data':['distributions']}}]"

 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'output'
```

My other links that only have a parent-> child do work:

```
 [routerLink]="['/output', {outlets: {'output': ['scenarios']}}]"
```

I have to assume I am formatting the routerLink incorrect for the parent->child->child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
routerLink = [
  '/output', {outlets: {'output': ['details', {outlets: {'data': ['distributions']}}]}}
]);
```

Comment: How to generate this dinamicaly? I vave a function, returning nice string for routerlink like `['${item.path}',{outlets:{'${item.outletName}':['${item.routeName}']}}]`, but when I call it in my template: [routerLink] = "makeRouterLink(navItem)", I've got this strange result on my page: ng-reflect-router-link="['selector',{outlets:{'selecto" - it's cutted!

Comment: @AntonPegov, please create a separate question